# The CSS isnt loading for react, and Im confused with the difference between the components css file, and adding it to the app.css overall

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is my Header component

```
import React from "react";



function Header() {
  return (
<div classname = "header">
    <nav classname = "navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div classname = "container">
            <button classname = "navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = "#Navbar">
                <span classname = "navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a href = "/#" classname = "navbar-brand"><h3>Portfolio</h3></a>

<div classname="btn-group">
    <button type="button" classname="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      My networking
    </button>
    <div classname="dropdown-menu">
      <a classname="dropdown-item" href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iJ1v7HyfodCWvg5OSQIXbUATrBM9mPwdqeIzKuld1qs/edit">Resume</a>
      <a classname="dropdown-item" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/tyler-goodman-39b289195/">LinkedIn</a>
      <a classname="dropdown-item" href="https://github.com/KawaiiSlave">Github</a>
    </div>
</div>

            <div classname = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "Navbar">
                <ul classname = "navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li classname = "nav-item"><a href = "#About" classname = "nav-link">About Me</a></li>
                    <li classname = "nav-item"><a href = "#Skills" classname = "nav-link">Skills</a></li>
                    <li classname = "nav-item"><a href = "#Projects" classname = "nav-link">My Projects</a></li>
                    <li classname = "nav-item"><a href = "#Contact" classname = "nav-link">My Contact Info</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Here is my app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from "./components/Header/header";
import About from './components/About/about';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <About/>

    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Ive got my stuff to render, but Im confused on where I should put my css. Does it go into the app.css file provided, or is it better off inside the living component, as that components css? If someone could give an example with their own css that would help tremendously. Im just kinda overwhelmed with react starting out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create specific CSS for your different components, you could use modules. I tend to make 'CSS modules' when I am creating a component I will use often, for instance a card module.

If you have a Card.js component, for instance, you might create a file called `card.module.css`.

At the top of Card.js, I would then import this using

```
import style from './card.module.css';
```

Within Card.js you can then add a className to an element using a JSX expression which accesses the imported `style` like so

```
<div className={style.header}>
```

Within the card.module.css file, you can then write css for .header

```
.header {
  // your CSS here
}
```

To re-iterate, your Card.js file will access `.header` through the imported `'style'`. If you were to add more CSS in your module, such as

```
.wrapper {
  // your CSS here
}
```

You could then too access that in your Card.js with

```
className={style.wrapper}
```